# How to delete column which contains a string using openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

```
wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

x = 0

for sheet in ws:
    for cell in sheet[0:]:
        if 'Attribute' in cell.value:
            x = x + 1
            print(x)
            ws.delete_cols(x)
        else:
            x = x + 1
wb.save('new_test.xlsx')
```

I am receiving below error
File "d:\Temp\Python\Excel_Test.py", line 33, in 
if 'Attribute' in cell.value:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: You need to check that the value in the cell is a string.

Answer (score 0):

May not be an optimal solution, but it works:

```
import openpyxl


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file_name.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

x = ws.max_row
y = ws.max_column
print(f"maxrow: {x}, maxcol: {y}")
for row in range(2, x+1):
    for col in range(1, y+1):
        #print(ws.cell(row=row, column=col).value)
        if 'Attribute' in str(ws.cell(row=row, column=col).value):
            ws.delete_cols(col)
wb.save('file_name.xlsx')
```